# Two subscripts in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

Word's equation editor seems to have an option for subscripts, subscripts, and both, but I can't find any option for a trailing and following subscript in the same go, as in "tpx". Any ideas?

Comment: you want a subscript on the left hand side, without a superscript? AND you want a subscript on the right hand side, without a superscript?

Comment: And you don't want an empty left side superscript box?

Comment: Yes exactly. These things are very common in math. http://mathbits.com/MathBits/TISection/Algebra1/Probab14.gif

Comment: Not possible in word. Check out [LaTeX](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics)